# Script for installing windows language packs through PowerShell with ISO not working

Tags: powershell

I want to install German, Spanish, French, and Japanese using an ISO and Powershell. However when we run the script and try to select a language from "windows display language" there are no other available options. Speech has options for the four languages though.

I also checked what's installed and two of them come back as staged, the other two say installed.

ISO we using: SW_DVD9_NTRL_Win_10_2004_32_64_ARM64_MultiLang_LangPackAll_LIP_X22-21307

**When I check what's installed it comes back with this:**

```
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers | ? Name -Like *LanguageExperiencePack* |
>> Format-List Name, PackageUserInformation


Name                 : Microsoft.LanguageExperiencePackde-DE
PackageUserInformation : {S-1-5-18 [S-1-5-18]: Staged}

Name                 : Microsoft.LanguageExperiencePackes-ES
PackageUserInformation : {S-1-5-18 [S-1-5-18]: Staged}

Name                 : Microsoft.LanguageExperiencePackfr-FR
PackageUserInformation : {S-1-5-21-3590531811-1086350273-2482590047-29077 [TS6FC\admcortes]: Installed}

Name                 : Microsoft.LanguageExperiencePackja-JP
PackageUserInformation : {S-1-5-21-3590531811-1086350273-2482590047-29077 [TS6FC\admcortes]: Installed}


**This is the script we run**

@ECHO OFF

IF EXIST "C:\Windows\InstallFlags\LanguagePacks" EXIT

ECHO =========================================
ECHO.
ECHO Installing German Language Pack...
ECHO.
ECHO =========================================


ECHO Basic Language Pack
dism /norestart /online /add-package /packagepath:"%~dp0de-de\Microsoft-Windows-Client-Language-Pack_x64_de-de.cab"

ECHO Basic Features
dism /norestart /online /add-package /packagepath:"%~dp0de-de\Microsoft-Windows-LanguageFeatures-Basic-de-de-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~.cab"

ECHO Handwriting Installation
dism /norestart /online /add-package /packagepath:"%~dp0de-de\Microsoft-Windows-LanguageFeatures-Handwriting-de-de-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~.cab"

ECHO OCR Installation
dism /norestart /online /add-package /packagepath:"%~dp0de-de\Microsoft-Windows-LanguageFeatures-OCR-de-de-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~.cab"

ECHO Speech Installation
dism /norestart /online /add-package /packagepath:"%~dp0de-de\Microsoft-Windows-LanguageFeatures-Speech-de-de-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~.cab"

ECHO TextToSpeech Installation
dism /norestart /online /add-package /packagepath:"%~dp0de-de\Microsoft-Windows-LanguageFeatures-TextToSpeech-de-de-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~.cab"


ECHO =========================================
ECHO.
ECHO Installing German Local Experience Pack...
ECHO.
ECHO =========================================


ECHO Local Experience Pack
dism /norestart /online /Add-ProvisionedAppxPackage /packagepath:"%~dp0de-de\LanguageExperiencePack.de-de.Neutral.appx" /LicensePath:"%~dp0\de-de\License.xml"


ECHO =========================================
ECHO.
ECHO German Local Experience Pack Installed!
ECHO.
ECHO =========================================





ECHO =========================================
ECHO.
ECHO Installing Spanish Language Pack...
ECHO.
ECHO =========================================


ECHO Basic Language Pack
dism /norestart /online /add-package /packagepath:"%~dp0es-es\Microsoft-Windows-Client-Language-Pack_x64_es-es.cab"

ECHO Basic Features
dism /norestart /online /add-package /packagepath:"%~dp0es-es\Microsoft-Windows-LanguageFeatures-Basic-es-es-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~.cab"

ECHO Handwriting Installation
dism /norestart /online /add-package /packagepath:"%~dp0es-es\Microsoft-Windows-LanguageFeatures-Handwriting-es-es-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~.cab"

ECHO OCR Installation
dism /norestart /online /add-package /packagepath:"%~dp0es-es\Microsoft-Windows-LanguageFeatures-OCR-es-es-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~.cab"

ECHO Speech Installation
dism /norestart /online /add-package /packagepath:"%~dp0es-es\Microsoft-Windows-LanguageFeatures-Speech-es-es-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~.cab"

ECHO TextToSpeech Installation
dism /norestart /online /add-package /packagepath:"%~dp0es-es\Microsoft-Windows-LanguageFeatures-TextToSpeech-es-es-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~.cab"


ECHO =========================================
ECHO.
ECHO Spanish Language Pack Installed!
ECHO.
ECHO =========================================


ECHO =========================================
ECHO.
ECHO Installing Spanish Local Experience Pack...
ECHO.
ECHO =========================================


ECHO Local Experience Pack
dism /norestart /online /Add-ProvisionedAppxPackage /packagepath:"%~dp0es-es\LanguageExperiencePack.es-es.Neutral.appx" /LicensePath:"%~dp0\es-es\License.xml"


ECHO =========================================
ECHO.
ECHO Spanish Local Experience Pack Installed!
ECHO.
ECHO =========================================





ECHO =========================================
ECHO.
ECHO Installing French Language Pack...
ECHO.
ECHO =========================================


ECHO Basic Language Pack
dism /norestart /online /add-package /packagepath:"%~dp0fr-fr\Microsoft-Windows-Client-Language-Pack_x64_fr-fr.cab"

ECHO Basic Features
dism /norestart /online /add-package /packagepath:"%~dp0fr-fr\Microsoft-Windows-LanguageFeatures-Basic-fr-fr-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~.cab"

ECHO Handwriting Installation
dism /norestart /online /add-package /packagepath:"%~dp0fr-fr\Microsoft-Windows-LanguageFeatures-Handwriting-fr-fr-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~.cab"

ECHO OCR Installation
dism /norestart /online /add-package /packagepath:"%~dp0fr-fr\Microsoft-Windows-LanguageFeatures-OCR-fr-fr-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~.cab"

ECHO Speech Installation
dism /norestart /online /add-package /packagepath:"%~dp0fr-fr\Microsoft-Windows-LanguageFeatures-Speech-fr-fr-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~.cab"

ECHO TextToSpeech Installation
dism /norestart /online /add-package /packagepath:"%~dp0fr-fr\Microsoft-Windows-LanguageFeatures-TextToSpeech-fr-fr-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~.cab"


ECHO =========================================
ECHO.
ECHO French Language Pack Installed!
ECHO.
ECHO =========================================


ECHO =========================================
ECHO.
ECHO French Local Experience Pack Installing...
ECHO.
ECHO =========================================


ECHO Local Experience Pack
dism /norestart /online /Add-ProvisionedAppxPackage /packagepath:"%~dp0fr-fr\LanguageExperiencePack.fr-fr.Neutral.appx" /LicensePath:"%~dp0\fr-fr\License.xml"


ECHO =========================================
ECHO.
ECHO French Local Experience Pack Installed!
ECHO.
ECHO =========================================





ECHO =========================================
ECHO.
ECHO Installing Japanese Language Pack...
ECHO.
ECHO =========================================


ECHO Basic Language Pack
dism /norestart /online /add-package /packagepath:"%~dp0ja-jp\Microsoft-Windows-Client-Language-Pack_x64_ja-jp.cab"


ECHO Basic Features
dism /norestart /online /add-package /packagepath:"%~dp0ja-jp\Microsoft-Windows-LanguageFeatures-Basic-ja-jp-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~.cab"

ECHO Handwriting Installation
dism /norestart /online /add-package /packagepath:"%~dp0ja-jp\Microsoft-Windows-LanguageFeatures-Handwriting-ja-jp-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~.cab"

ECHO OCR Installation
dism /norestart /online /add-package /packagepath:"%~dp0ja-jp\Microsoft-Windows-LanguageFeatures-OCR-ja-jp-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~.cab"

ECHO Speech Installation
dism /norestart /online /add-package /packagepath:"%~dp0ja-jp\Microsoft-Windows-LanguageFeatures-Speech-ja-jp-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~.cab"

ECHO TextToSpeech Installation
dism /norestart /online /add-package /packagepath:"%~dp0ja-jp\Microsoft-Windows-LanguageFeatures-TextToSpeech-ja-jp-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~.cab"


ECHO =========================================
ECHO.
ECHO Japanese Language Pack Installed!
ECHO.
ECHO =========================================


ECHO =========================================
ECHO.
ECHO Installing Japanese Local Experience Pack...
ECHO.
ECHO =========================================

ECHO Local Experience Pack
dism /norestart /online /Add-ProvisionedAppxPackage /packagepath:"%~dp0ja-jp\LanguageExperiencePack.ja-jp.Neutral.appx" /LicensePath:"%~dp0\ja-jp\License.xml"


ECHO =========================================
ECHO.
ECHO Japanese Local Experience Pack Installed!
ECHO.
ECHO =========================================



MD "C:\Windows\InstallFlags\LanguagePacks"



PAUSE
```